# Does iText support OCR?

Tags: java, itext

I would like to ask a question about iText.
I am facing a problem searching for text in a PDF file.

I can create a plain text file using the `getTextfromPage()` method as described in the following code sample:

```
/** The original PDF that will be parsed. */
    public static final String PREFACE = "D:/B.pdf";
    /** The resulting text file. */
    public static final String RESULT = "D:/Result.txt";
public void ParsePDF(String From, String Destination) throws IOException{

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PREFACE);  
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(RESULT));              
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {                          
         out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));  
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        reader.close();

    }
```

I'm trying to find a specific `String` in the resulting text like this:

```
    public void FindWords(String From) {
        try{
            String ligneLue;            
            LineNumberReader lnr=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(RESULT));
            try{                
                while((ligneLue=lnr.readLine())!=null){
                    SearchForSVHC(ligneLue,SvhcList);
                }
            }
            finally{                
                lnr.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);}
        }   
    public void SearchForSVHC(String Ligne,List<String> List){
        for(String CAS :List){
            if(Ligne.contains(CAS)){
                System.out.print("Yes  "+CAS);
                break;
        }}
    }
```

My problem is that some PDFs I'm parsing consist of scanned images, which means that there is no real text, just pixels.

Does iText support Optical Character Recognition (OCR) and as a follow-up question: is there a way to determine if a PDF consists of scanned images?

Comment: No it does not see the last line of this doc http://www.itextpdf.com/itext.php

Answer (score 4):

I've done a very thorough edit of your question before answering it.

When a PDF consists of scanned images, there is no real text to parse, there are just images with pixels that *look* like text. You'd need to do OCR to know what is actually written on such a scanned page, and iText doesn't support OCR.

Regarding the follow-up question: it's very hard to find out if a PDF contains scanned images. A first give-away would be: there's only an image in the page, and there's no text.

However: as you don't know anything about the nature of the images (maybe you have a PDF containing nothing but holiday photos), it's very hard to find out if the PDF is a document full of scanned pages of text (that is: rasterized text).

Comment: thank you very much Mr @Bruno Lowagie , so in this case isn't posssible to warn the user that the file contains image ,and he must do his research visually! :(

Comment: Well, you could parse the pages for text, and if you don't find any, inform the user that you couldn't find any text and that the PDF therefor should be OCR'ed first.

Comment: Yes ,I have an exemple that contains 5 page ,the 3 one are image and the other one are texts,in this case can I do PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i) and find out the type of this page for exemple image or text (I think Pdfbox !!! and thank you

Comment: Yes, both iText as well as PDFBox, can inform you about the presence of text and/or images on each page.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, iText does have an [OCR product](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfocr), which uses Tesseract 4.x. You can get all of its documentation on their [Knowledge Base](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/search?q=&l=pdfocr&max=500).

Here's a quick example listed over there, on how to OCR an image into a PDF/A-3u file.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.OcrPdfCreator;
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.tesseract4.Tesseract4LibOcrEngine;
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.tesseract4.Tesseract4OcrEngineProperties;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class JDoodle {

    private static List LIST_IMAGES_OCR = Arrays.asList(new File("invoice_front.jpg"));
    private static String OUTPUT_PDF = "/myfiles/hello.pdf";
    private static final String DEFAULT_RGB_COLOR_PROFILE_PATH = "profiles/sRGB_CS_profile.icm";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        OcrPdfCreatorProperties properties = new OcrPdfCreatorProperties();
        properties.setPdfLang("en"); //we need to define a language to make it PDF/A compliant

        OcrPdfCreator ocrPdfCreator = new OcrPdfCreator(new Tesseract4LibOcrEngine(new Tesseract4OcrEngineProperties()), properties);
        try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(OUTPUT_PDF)) {
            ocrPdfCreator.createPdfA(LIST_IMAGES_OCR, writer, getRGBPdfOutputIntent()).close();
        }
    }

    public static PdfOutputIntent getRGBPdfOutputIntent() throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(DEFAULT_RGB_COLOR_PROFILE_PATH);
        return new PdfOutputIntent("", "",
                "", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", is);
    }

}
```

It's coming late, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I have a problem with couple of pdf files. Itextpdf reads most of the document fine but it also reads weird characters sometimes. Does this also solves my problem?

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan, hard to help without seeing something specific. Do you have a PDF document you can share?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/73) support case says that iText does not support OCR. Recognizing if a image contains text is as simple as passing the image to a OCR processor and check if the result is meaningful.

Comment: thank you,My problem is that I work with a systematic search. User know nothing about research and PDF format .. is it posssible in this case to warn the user that the file contains image he must do his research visually!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using a combination of iText and Tesseract (a google OCR implementation).

First I would put an interface around the OCR engine. This allows me to swap it out later.

```
public interface IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine {

class OCRChunk {
    private Rectangle location;
    private String text;
    public OCRChunk(Rectangle rectangle, String text){
        this.location = rectangle;
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getText(){ return text; }
    public Rectangle getLocation(){return location;}
}

List<OCRChunk> doOCR(BufferedImage bufferedImage);
}
```

This interface essentially says "OCR engines return objects that are a combination of locations (rectangles) and text"

Then we need to create a ITextExtractionStrategy that transforms `ImageRenderInfo` events to `TextRenderInfo` using the OCREngine

```
public class OCRTextExtractionStrategy implements ITextExtractionStrategy {

private final ITextExtractionStrategy innerStrategy;
private final IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine opticalCharacterRecognitionEngine;
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OCRTextExtractionStrategy.class.getSimpleName());

public OCRTextExtractionStrategy(ITextExtractionStrategy innerStrategy, IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine opticalCharacterRecognitionEngine){
    this.innerStrategy = innerStrategy;
    this.opticalCharacterRecognitionEngine = opticalCharacterRecognitionEngine;
}

public String getResultantText() {
    return innerStrategy.getResultantText();
}

public void eventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType) {
    // handle images
    if(eventType == EventType.RENDER_IMAGE){

        // extract coordinates
        ImageRenderInfo imageRenderInfo  = (ImageRenderInfo) iEventData;
        float x = imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I11);
        float y = imageRenderInfo.getImageCtm().get(Matrix.I22);

        // attempt to parse image
        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = imageRenderInfo.getImage().getBufferedImage();
            for(IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine.OCRChunk chunk : opticalCharacterRecognitionEngine.doOCR(bufferedImage)){
                if(chunk.getText() != null && !chunk.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    chunk.getLocation().translate((int) x, (int) y);
                    TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = pseudoTextRenderInfo(chunk);
                    if(textRenderInfo !=  null)
                        innerStrategy.eventOccurred( textRenderInfo, EventType.RENDER_TEXT);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { logger.severe(e.getLocalizedMessage()); }

    }
    // handle anything else
    else {
        innerStrategy.eventOccurred(iEventData, eventType);
    }
}

private TextRenderInfo pseudoTextRenderInfo(IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine.OCRChunk chunk){

    // dummy graphics state
    ModifiableGraphicsState mgs = new ModifiableGraphicsState();
    try {
        mgs.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont());
        mgs.setCtm(new Matrix(  1,0,0,
                                0,1,0,
                                0,0,1));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    // dummy text matrix
    float x = chunk.getLocation().x;
    float y = chunk.getLocation().y;
    Matrix textMatrix = new Matrix( x, 0,0,
                                0, y, 0,
                                0,0,0);

    // return TextRenderInfo object
    return new TextRenderInfo(
            new PdfString(chunk.getText(), ""),
            mgs,
            textMatrix,
            new Stack<CanvasTag>()

    );
}

public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() { return null; }

}
```

This class performs that translation.
There is some magic going around with coordinate-transformation (which I may not yet have gotten right perfectly).

The grunt of the work is performed in the method `pseudoTextRenderInfo` which converts the results given by the `IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine` to `TextRenderInfo` objects.

In order for that to work, we need a `CanvasGraphicsState` that is modifiable.
Which the default implementation isn't.
So let's extend the default.

```
class ModifiableGraphicsState extends CanvasGraphicsState{

private Matrix ctm;

public ModifiableGraphicsState(){ super(); }

public Matrix getCtm() { return ctm; }
public ModifiableGraphicsState setCtm(Matrix ctm){this.ctm = ctm; return this;};
public void updateCtm(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f) { updateCtm(new Matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f)); }
public void updateCtm(Matrix newCtm) {
    ctm = newCtm.multiply(ctm);
}

}
```

Lastly, we need an implementation of the `IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine`.
This concrete implementation was done using Tesseract (tess4j if you're using Java).

```
public class TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine implements IOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine {

private Tesseract tesseract;

public TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine(File tesseractDataDirectory, String languageCode){
    tesseract = new Tesseract();

    // set data path
    if(!tesseractDataDirectory.exists())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    tesseract.setDatapath(tesseractDataDirectory.getAbsolutePath());

    // set language code
    if(!new File(tesseractDataDirectory, languageCode + ".traineddata").exists())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    tesseract.setLanguage(languageCode);
}

public List<OCRChunk> doOCR(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    List<OCRChunk> textChunkLocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for(Rectangle rectangle : tesseract.getSegmentedRegions(bufferedImage, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD)){
            String text = tesseract.doOCR(bufferedImage, rectangle);
            textChunkLocationList.add(new OCRChunk(rectangle, text));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    return textChunkLocationList;
}
}
```

You can then call the code as follows:

```
// initialize tesseract
TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine ocrEngine = new TesseractOpticalCharacterRecognitionEngine(new File("tessdata_fast"), "eng");

// create document
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new File("scanned_document.pdf")));

// extract text
SimpleTextExtractionStrategy simpleTextExtractionStrategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
OCRTextExtractionStrategy ocrTextExtractionStrategy = new OCRTextExtractionStrategy(simpleTextExtractionStrategy, ocrEngine);
    new PdfCanvasProcessor(ocrTextExtractionStrategy).processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(1));

// display
System.out.println(simpleTextExtractionStrategy.getResultantText());
```

Comment: In `OCRTextExtractionStrategy` you ignore much of the image transformation matrix, in particular in case of an image rotated by 90° that code collapses everything to the origin. Then you translate the text chunks by the image dimensions. And later you use the text chunk position as scale values for a text matrix. I haven't checked whether that all by chance levels out but it looks weird to start with.

Comment: I'm sure none of that cancels out, and the effects in anything but a non-trivial PDF are horrendous.
This code is merely meant as a general guideline on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

No iText has nothing to do with OCR. A PDF originated from a scanned book can contain pages as images, as text or (as is often done to keep the visual original plus text search ability) both; of course, if it contains text it's because some OCR has already been done.

To detect that a PDF contains only images and no text can be a tricky thing, but a simple heuristic would be to try to extract the text (see [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277)) and decide that the PDF is pure-image if it returns (almost) empty text for all (most) pages.

Comment: thank you ,My problem is that I work with a systematic search. User know nothing about research and PDF format .. is it posssible in this case to warn the user that the file contains image he must do his research visually!